# djangorestframework :type object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/`
it get error : `djangorestframework :type object  has no attribute 'id'`
Why can't I get the id value? 
Please help me,thank you!

Here is my code

serialize.py

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    link = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(source='id',  view_name='movie_detail')
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ( 'link', 'title')


class MovieDetail(object):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^movies/$', MovieList.as_view(), name='movie_list'),
    url(r'^movies/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', MovieDetail.as_view(), name='movie_detail'),
```

how can I edit it to show the result like this:

```
"results": [
        { 
            "link": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/1", 
            "title": "test", 
        },   
        { 
            "link": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/2", 
            "title": "test", 
        },   
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`HyperlinkedRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#hyperlinkedrelatedfield) must have a `source` that points at a related object on the model. You are looking for a [`HyperlinkedIdentityField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#hyperlinkedidentityfield), which will give a link for the current object, similar to what a [`HyperlinkedModelSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#hyperlinkedmodelserializer) will do automatically for you.

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    link = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='movie_detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ( 'link', 'title', )
```